# map in array not working in ngOnChange event Angular 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am new to Angular and this is my first app. I have a parent component which gets data from an API using service. With the response from the service, I create an array and pass it as attribute to a child component. In the child component, I have the follow ngOnChange event

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    console.log("Mode total in mode", this.modeTotal);
    this.modeTotal.map(mode => {
      console.log("For each");
      this.doughnutChartLabels.push(mode.name);
      this.doughnutChartData.push(mode.total);
      console.log(`Loop inside onChange Name: ${mode.name} and Total: ${mode.total}`);
    });
    console.log("DoughnutChartLabels", this.doughnutChartLabels);
    console.log("DoughnutChartData", this.doughnutChartData);
}
```

The problem I am facing is the console above and below the map function is working, printing the content of **modeTotal**, **doughnutChartLabels** and **doughnutChartData** but not the string inside the map function. And the modeTotal has the array of data which I expect to be returned.

What am I missing?

Note: I push data into the modeTotal from another component which receives data from an API. The modeTotal is not getting updated even when new data is pushed into it.

Comment: which string is not getting printed?

Comment: This statement `console.log(\`Loop inside onChange Name: ${mode.name} and Total: ${mode.total}\`);`

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz demo

Comment: maybe you want to use .forEach? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Tried with forEach too. No luck.

Comment: can you show what do you see inside  console.log("Mode total in mode", JSON.stirngify(this.modeTotal));

Comment: I get empty brackets when I stringify modeTotal but if I print it as an Object I get `Mode total in mode 
[]
0: Object { total: 650, name: "Credit Cards" }
1: Object { total: 1000, name: "Paytm" }
2: Object { total: 960, name: "Debit Card" }
length: 3
__proto__: Array []`

Comment: it should not be empty if you have data

Comment: It is showing empty. I even tried to print the changes variable from the argument, which has data in the currentValue field, but when I tried to print the length of currentValue it returns 0. but the currentValue has data same as the previous comment

Comment: Please check the screenshot of the console and the code in the below links
https://ibb.co/mNuBuG
https://ibb.co/jHuBuG

Comment: Please edit your question and include your full code, parent components and how your data behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event will not occur on an array when a new data is pushed into it since the variable is referring to the same object. Try adding a local variable to monitor the push changes.